# I am trying to align my navigation links and logo correctly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the logo in the absolute center but also have the navigation links where they are. This is what it looks like now [image]

My CSS:

```
    .logo {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
    }

    nav {
      margin-top: 2em;
      display: inline-block;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: 0.8s opacity;
      float: right;
      margin-right: 4em;
    }

    nav ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }

    nav li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 1em;
    }

    nav a {
      font-weight: 900;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 1rem;
      padding: .75;
      color: white;
      transition: 0.3s color;
    }

HTML: (extremely basic right now)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Placeholder Name</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira Sans' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <header>
      <img class="logo" src="images/placeholder.png" alt="Placeholder Logo">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <section class="home-hero">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="title">Turning your Tennis dreams into reality
          <span>with professional interaction and planning</span>
        </h1>
        <a href="#" class="button button-outline">See Our Schedule</a>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>

  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("nav").css("opacity", '1');
   });
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".title").css("transform", 'translateX(0%)');
   });
   $(function() {
     $('nav li.home a').addClass('active');
   });
  </script>
</html>
```

If you require anything else, let me know instead of just instantly downvoting, thanks <3

Comment: Could you go ahead and post your html also?

Comment: And maybe even link us to your website if it is live?

Comment: @KirkHadden HTML added.

Comment: @RickyDam live site: https://sapsrp.com/rick/

Comment: Could you please read [ask]? Especially the bit about "Writing good titles".

Comment: Hey @Nitro. Consider leaving out any code that doesn't specifically have to do with the question. For example, we don't need the jQuery - or the doctype etc. Make a small example with just the bare bones, like the jsFiddle I provided in my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit for responsive Header:

Put your logo image in it's own `<div>`, and:

```
div.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Edit for whatever size you need */
@media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
    .logo {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want it so once it gets down to a certain size, it moves the nav UNDER the logo too

Comment: Ah. See the edited version above, then. You can use a media query to handle that.

Comment: Only problem there is now I have this https://gyazo.com/b657016f2242378f4701aa8b49c7cdee

Comment: I want it inside that image

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Here is one - but really, you'll want to take responsive layouts into consideration...

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/31p8dL1d/

### Markup

```
<header class="site-header">
  <div class="image-w logo">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200" alt="Logo">
  </div>
  <nav class="site-navigation">
    <ul class="item-list">
      <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

### styles

```
.image-w img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.site-header {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: right; /* you'll likely use float or flex */
  position: relative;
}

.site-header .logo {
  max-width: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.site-navigation {
  /* float: right; if not using align right for inline-block */
  display: inline-block;
}

.site-navigation .item-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.site-navigation .item-list li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.site-navigation .item-list a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1.4rem;
}
```